# is an http login form vulnerable over not public network?

Tags: http, security, https, server

I have an web app mounted on my own server with a public IP, the application allow the user login and  insert some data to mysql through the smartphone.

The user enter to my app with mobile data, so my question is, how vulnerable can be this data?

Comment: Yes, very - the operator of a random wifi network a user stumbled across & decided to use could see everything. HTTP*S* mitigates this risk.

Comment: user doesn't have possibility to connect with public wifis, i assign the smartphone when him enter to work, and when labor is ended the smartphone is returned.
assuming this conditions is vulnerable the login?

Comment: Yes, the login is still vulnerable if it is transmitted over plain/text HTTP, it should be transmitted over TLS-encrypted HTTPS instead, regardless of the type of network used (WiFi, cellular, etc).